# Not able to import json file on google colab

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import json file for the first time on google colab. This file is getting imported on my jupyter notebook without causing any problem.

This is my code:-

```
df=pd.read_json("E:/Data Science/FlipRobo/Assignments/NLP Sept project/Cell_Phones_and_Accessories.json", orient='records',dtype='dict')
df.head()
```

It is giving error as below:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bb0b9f3e9bb6> in <module>()
----> 1 df=pd.read_json("E:/Data Science/FlipRobo/Assignments/NLP Sept project/Cell_Phones_and_Accessories.json", orient='records',dtype='dict')
      2 df.head()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1106         else:
   1107             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1108                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1109             )
   1110 

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Use `with open('file.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: data = json.loads(f.read())`, then use `pd.read_json(data)` read the documentation for `read_json`. If that doesn't work, you need to include a reproducible example of the file contents. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a **local** file from a **cloud** service. First you have to upload you file to the colab environment.